# How does a transformation domain differ from a spatial domain?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, imaging

In the context of single-pixel imaging, the following statement is given:

"*Global transformation has a property that each point (coefficient) in the transformation domain
is a weighted sum of all points in the spatial domain and each point (image pixel) in the spatial
domain is also a weighted sum of all points in the transformation domain*" [1]

To my understanding the coefficient is a basis pattern, like the ones presented inside the blue and red rectangles in the figure below.

**But what is the transformation domain and how does it differ from the spatial domain?**

**How can each point in one domain be the sum of points in the other domain?**

[image]

---

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8jKZ.jpg) Hadamard single-pixel imaging versus Fourier single-pixel imaging, Z. Zhang *et al*. [*Opt. Express* **25**, 19619-19639 ,(2017)](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-25-16-19619&id=370424)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most general sense, if your basis patterns have no obvious interpretation, you first need to decide which pixel in the transformed domain will correspond to which basis pattern. To represent the whole space of $N \times N$ pixels, you (in general) also need $N \times N$ basis patterns, so you will end up with exactly as many patterns as you have pixels in the original image, and can thus assign each pixel in the transformed domain a specific pattern.

Next you figure out how much of each pattern you must add up to get back your original image. So you write your original image as a weighted sum over all the patterns. If all patterns are linearly independent, there is always a unique way to do this. Now you simply color each pixel in the transformed domain according to the weight. In greyscale that means a coefficient of $1$ makes that particular pixel white, $0$ makes it black, and everything in between is some level of grey. This is the way in which the image in the original domain is the sum over all pixels in the transformed domain. The reverse is also true, but a bit harder to visualize.

This transformed domain often has some advantages. Many coefficients may be close to $0$ and can then be ignored without distorting the original too much. Or the transformed image might be more resilient to some discretization.

For specific transformations, there is a natural choice of which pattern is assigned to which pixel. Fourier transform is one of these cases. The center pixel is usually assigned a constant pattern of all white pixels, and moving in any direction gives patterns with plane waves with shorter and shorter wavelengths the further from the center you go.

Comment: Thank you so much.